# Why can method taking immutable `&self` modify data in field with mutex?

Tags: methods, rust, mutex, immutability

Consider the following code (also on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=147c6da9a409b12dc28ec6b9dbee6229)):

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, sync::Mutex};

struct MyStruct {
    dummy_map: Mutex<HashMap<i64, i64>>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        MyStruct {
            dummy_map: Mutex::new(Default::default()),
        }
    }

    pub fn insert(&self, key: i64, val: i64) { // <-- immutable &self
        self.dummy_map.lock().unwrap().insert(key, val); // <-- insert in dummy_map
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct::new();
    let key = 1;
    s.insert(key, 1);
    assert!(s.dummy_map.lock().unwrap().get(&key).is_some());
}
```

The code runs wihout panic, meaning `insert` takes immutable `&self`, but still it can insert into the map (which is wrapped in `Mutex`).

How come this is possible?

Would it be better for `insert` to take `&mut self`? To indicate that a field is modified...

If `dummy_map` is not wrapped in a `Mutex`, the code does not compile (as I`d expect). See [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5f4f42864661542e1bbc31b95bfc4b94).

Comment: Is there a best practice for method signatures in such cases? `insert(&self, ...)` vs `insert(&mut self, ...)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Mutex` is one of the Rust types that implements "interior mutability" (see [the docs for `Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/index.html) for discussion on that).

In short, types that implement "interior mutability" circumvent the compile-time ownership checks in favor of runtime checks. In this case, `Mutex` enforces the mutability rules at runtime by ensuring only one thread can access the data using its [`lock()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.lock) and [`try_lock()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.try_lock) methods.

Both locking methods return an owned [`MutexGuard`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html) which can provide read-only and mutable access to the data through the `Deref` and `DerefMut` traits, respectively.

In the end, this means that the variable that needs to be `mut` is the returned `MutexGuard`, not the `Mutex` itself.

Answer (score 8):

`mut` is kind of a misnomer in Rust, it actually means "exclusive access" (which you need to be able to mutate a value but is slightly more general). In this case, you obviously can't get exclusive access to the `Mutex` itself (because the whole point is to share it between threads), and therefore you can't get exclusive access to `self` either. However, you can get temporary exclusive access to the data inside the `Mutex`, at which point it becomes possible to mutate it. Kinda like what happens with `Cell` and `RefCell` too.